# Change of basis and dimension of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to wrap my head around some basic concepts here. I have some vector subspace $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W} = \{Ax \mid x \in \mathcal{V}\}$, where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix. Is it always true that $\dim(\mathcal{W}) = \dim(\mathcal{V})$? If $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{V}$, how can we find a basis of $\mathcal{W}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to assume that $A$ is invertible, which an orthogonal matrix is, to conclude $W=A(V)$ has the same dimension as $V$.

It's because both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ takes any linearly independent set of vectors to a linearly independent set.

> Suppose $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are independent and $\sum_i\lambda_i\,Av_i=0$, then apply $A^{-1}$ to obtain $\sum_i\lambda_iv_i=0$ so each $\lambda_i=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are working with finite-dimensional subspaces.

- In general, if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\dim (W) = \dim (V)$, then $W = V$, so any basis of $V$ is a basis of $W$.
- You have defined $W$ as the column space of $A$ (span of the columns of $A$). If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then the dimension of $W$ is the number of columns of $A$. In your specific situation, $A$ is a square invertible matrix (because it is orthogonal) with $\dim(V)$ columns so $\dim(W) = \dim(V)$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $A$ has $\dim(V)$ columns? $A$ can be $n \times n$ while $\dim(W)$ can be $< n$, it seems?

Comment: $A$ has $\dim(V)$ columns because you wrote "$Ax$" where $x \in V$ (i.e. $x$ is represented by an $\dim(V)$-dimensional vector, so $A$ is a $\dim(V) \times \dim(V)$ matrix). In general yes $W$ (the column space of $A$) can be strictly smaller than $\dim(V)$, but if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then it equals $\dim(V)$.